# Excel 2016 VBA Code for checkbox to enter yes or no up on selection from userform1

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

OK I'm new to this community and I have had great help from a number of users from other parts of this site. I posted a question yesterday and I haven't gotten any answer yet. I was browsing the site for excel vba questions and came across this community and I thought I might have posted the question in the wrong section so why not try here and might be someone from here can help me with this. If this is duplicate question then I really apologies for this.

I have a userform made with the help of few users off this site and all functionality is working as it should be. I had to made few changes in one of the sheets and now I'm stuck that how to get it working with the newly added options. Its a checkbox1 which I've added on the userform1 that if and when its pressed or checked the data from the first two textboxes will also gets copied in a sheet named profitloss (same workbook). 13 sheets. 12 for months and one for profitloss. I need the vba code to get the checkbox1 working so that only when its checked only then it replicates the data in profitloss.

If anybody can help with this I would highly appreciate it. In a real predicament here! and any help is very helpful to achieve this. Thanks in advance. Code is below which is in userform1 at the moment.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim SheetName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

SheetName = ComboBox1.Value
Set ws = Sheets(SheetName)

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
Label8.Caption = "         Balance is: " & ws.Cells(LastRow, 7).Value


 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim dcc As Long
 Dim abc As Worksheet, pfl As Worksheet

 Set abc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Value)
 Set pfl = Sheets("ProfitLoss")

 With abc

 dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
.Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value

End With

With pfl
dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
.Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
 End With

 TextBox1.Text = ""
 TextBox2.Text = ""
 TextBox3.Text = ""
 TextBox4.Text = ""
 TextBox5.Text = ""

 End Sub
```

I can share screenshot of the sheet and userform for clear understanding. I don't have excel vba background hence I struggle with explaning the question to be honest. Your help is much appreciated in this and for also your patience. Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Edit:

OK I edited did as suggested by @FreeMan (thanks for that) and I've gotten this far in:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Set abc = 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Value)
Set pfl = Sheets("ProfitLoss")

With abc

 dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
.Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value

End With


End Sub
```

OK this works, kinda. It's not giving any error which I suppose is always a good thing! but, but its making double entries in january 2019. Which is not cool. What's happening is, I select the month from the comboxbox1 and lets say January 2019 and in comment I write rent and in rent I enter 1 and as soon as I click the check box the entry is added in january 2019 sheet, even before I click add the entry button on userform1. Now the same thing what I said above, and then I click the button add entry on userform1 then it makes the entry in January 2019 and also in profitloss. So it works but making double entries when click add data.

I'm 1000% sure I messed up, I know it already! lol but I dont know what it is and how to stop it from entering the data as soon as checbox1 is clicked. Your help is much needed and appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: In your existing code, you have `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` and `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()`. These are "event handlers" and they handle the event of `Click` or `Change` on the applicable form control. You need to add an event handler for `Checkbox1` that does what you need it to do. You've got enough code here to copy/paste/modify into your new event handler to get it done. NB: Make sure you select your form in the VBE's top left dropdown box, then select the "Change" option in the top right dropdown box. (Con't...)

Comment: Do **not** try to type the method signature yourself - too much effort and a _very_ high chance of getting it wrong.

Comment: @FreeMan many thanks for your fast reply, it's much appreciated! Honest. I understand what you said, kinda, the tiny bit of knowledge which I have I will apply it now. I'll try your suggestion and my only confusion is the code to enter in change handler. I will try my best to copy paste and see how it goes. Once again I appreciate your help. I will update in few ticks that how it went! Cheers.

Comment: Do your best, then [edit] your post to include your new code and the specific thing you're having issues with.

Comment: @FreeMan I did my best and edited the OP to include what I've done and what its doing to me now lol. I appreciate your help, many thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: Many apologies in taking long time to reply/edit OP as I struggle with code and confuse myself at every line. I appreciate your patience. Cheers.

Comment: Very helpful! It sounds like you don't actually want to update the worksheet when you set the checkbox, you only want to update when you click the button _and_ if the checkbox is set. Move your newly added code out of `Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()` and put it into `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`. Not sure if your initial question was unclear or I just misread it, but it's much more clear now.

Comment: @FreeMan You probably read it right and you are right. It's me 99.100% of the time. I'm not a excel person let alone VBA! hence my explanation sound like a novel because I start from today when I woke up and..... I don't know terms which are used in excel vba. You and few others have helped me greatly in doing what I'm doing. Having said that, yes I only want data to be copied onto the profitloss "If" the checkbox1 is clicked, If not clicked the data should enter in the month which was selected from the combobox1. Data only goes in PL if checkbox1 is clicked. (Contd..)

Comment: Where I messed up in my novel is that I do need worksheet to be updated but, but when the checkbox1 is also checked on the userform1 the data also should transfer onto PL sheet. I will do what you suggested and also add a link of screenshot in like 5 mins or so. I know I'm bad at explaining. Please accept my apologies. Cheers.

Comment: Quick note. I think it worked!! I'm gobsmacked tbh. I think it worked!! I'm going to quickly try a few dummy entries and make sure I'm excited correctly lol. Update here in a few ticks. Cheers.

Comment: It didn't worked.. Its doing the same thing, if checkbox1 is unchecked the data still going into profitloss sheet and there's a blank entry in january 2019 if checkbox1 is not clicked. I tried to modify the code but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few go-rounds and a suggestion to move the comments to chat, it looks to me like this is what you want:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim dcc As Long
  Dim abc As Worksheet, pfl As Worksheet

  Set abc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Value)
  Set pfl = Sheets("ProfitLoss")

  With abc
    dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
  End With
```

Note the difference here - we're only moving items to the P/L sheet *If* checkbox1 is checked

```
  If CheckBox1.Value Then 'this is a shorter way of writing the conditional
    With pfl
      dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
      .Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
      .Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
      .Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
      .Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
      .Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
      .Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
    End With
  End If

  TextBox1.text = ""
  TextBox2.text = ""
  TextBox3.text = ""
  TextBox4.text = ""
  TextBox5.text = ""

End Sub
```

A couple of code comments:

- Excellent job with declaring `worksheet` variables and using them!
- You have multiple declarations (`abc` & `pfl`) in one `Dim` statement. Most people mess this up and only declare the type for the last one leaving the earlier ones as `Variant`. You got this right, too!
- Your variable names leave a bit to be desired.

  - Another programmer in the future (maybe even future you) will have a hard time deciphering what `abc` means.
  - Maybe something like `selectedWorksheet`, or even better (since `.Select` is a `Worksheet` method) would be `destinationWorksheet` or `desiredWorksheet`. #NamingIsHard
  - `pfl` is *more* obvious, but still obtuse, maybe `profitAndLossSheet`. *Say what you mean and mean what you say.*
  - `dcc` seems to be the last used row, so just call it `lastRow` or `lastUsedRow`
  - *#NamingIsStillHard*
- Indent your code. It's much easier to see where code blocks start and end when you do that. It's really easy to skip over or miss things when code is *not* indented neatly.

Comment: First of all I appreciate your patience and for providing the code. Also to take your time in explaning that how and what's going on! I well and truly appreciate it. And, It worked! Like a charm! I tried and before I tried I read your answer few times to fully understand and grasp it. Then tried and it worked straightaway. No errors whatsoever. Tried multiple months multiple entries and checkbox1 if doing what it should do only if its clicked. I will keep in mind all the pointers and suggestions, I will. I'll mark this answered and many thanks for this, much appreciated. (Contd...)

Comment: I have to make another userform for data entry I'll again try my best to keep in mind your pointers which you mentioned above and work with them. I'm currently designing the other userform and come evening (UK) I'll be either a happy bunny or you'll see another post here by me lol. I'm hoping to get that one right but then it's me and I know me lol. I will mess it up by being extra careful lol. You have a nice day or evening @FreeMan  Cheers.

Comment: Happy to help, @MT, and glad that I managed to get it all right on the first shot! (I don't always...) A couple of additional suggestions: *Provide actual names for your form controls, `Checkbox1` will be pretty meaningless in 6 months, but `WriteToProfitLossSheet` will be fairly clear. *Don't apologize for "taking a long time to respond" - it's your question, not mine & I wasn't doing nothing waiting for your response ;) *You may consider posting future questions on [SO] as it's more coding oriented than SuperUser is.

Comment: lol OK will keep in mind and yes I don't have a vivid imagination for names. O by the way I did asked there and nobody answered. But, I've updated the question there and have credited you for it. I did that in case somebody is looking for same/similar thing and he/she should be able to find it there as well. I will be changing the names of boxes and labels in the new userform which I'm working on now. Like I said come evening in the UK and I'll be on my laptop to make two, lol yes not one but two check boxes work! I have a feeling it's going to be a fun evening lol. Cheers!

Comment: tagging that question with [VBA] and/or [Excel-VBA] would have helped garner more attention.

Comment: I tried but it's something about my new account that I cant. It only allowed me excel or checkbox. I don't have enough reputation or something along the lines it said. Anyway, I just had a look at your profile and you're an everton man! Small world!! Mersyside, LP good old days, I have someone there closer to me. Nice to meet you!! now, time for a cuppa and then back to work. Cheers.